# How to display movieclips out of stage bounds in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently working on a launcher game in flash:

1. the hero throws a stick in the air, which then travels long distances, hitting all kinds of objects.
2. while the stick makes its flight, the hero's dog runs after it, hitting all kinds of objects etc...

**My problem:** I want to split the screen horizontally where you follow the stick on the upper part of the screen, and you follow the dog on the lower part of the screen.

Right now I've implemented the stick movement. Technically, the stick only moves to the center of the stage, once its coordinates are at stage center, its all the other objects that move according to the x and y speed of the stick.

**Now my problem is:** how do I manage the display of the dog? I hoped that I could find some class that creates a sort of viewport, allowing me to display objects that are way out of the bounds of my stage but thus far I didn't find what I needed.

The only solution I can think of would be to create 2 instances of each movieclip whenever one is added to my stage, and add the copy as child of another movieClip, at converted x and y coordinates) but then I would have to do everything twice (eg: if the stick destroys something, its copy has to be destroyed as well).

Any idea on how I could do this without torturing my players' processor (and jeopardizing my own sanity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer to this problem so I thought I'd share what I did.

The solution was to implement a Virtual Camera, using the transform.matrix property

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

Here's a tutorial on how to achieve this.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuhJkEWAbq8

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem is **blitting**, which is drawing the pixels from a DisplayObject, similar to what you see [here](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2012/06/endless-scrolling-bathroom.html).

Another (which will probably serve you well in the long term and doesn't need to be mutually exclusive from the first), is to **make the whole thing data-driven**. You'll simply build two different Views that either get the same data or different subsets of the data, and then represent the data according to their own rules.

When an object disappears from the data, its representation disappears from both Views at the same time. Technically, you're probably still doing the work twice, but if you're smart with how you write your Classes, this doesn't necessarily mean extra code.

Finally, you may want to consider using [scrollRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect).